# enviar archivos desde mi service en eclipse a android

Tags: java, android, rest

Tengo un dilema. Estoy intentando enviar un archivo que tengo en mi base de datos a mi aplicación android. Tengo mi servicio que obtiene un byte[] pero al llamarlo desde mi aplicación android, se cae. No sé como enviar dicho archivo, si enviarlo como lo estoy enviando (byte[]) o de alguna otra manera para que pueda ser recibido desde mi aplicativo. Resalto que utilizo servicio REST. En android solo  llamo a la url de mi servicio, el cual me devuelve un bean con la data. Cualquier adicional que requieran para que me puedan ayudar estoy atento. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí hago el llamado desde android. Es un service donde envío el request y el parametro que necesita.

@GET("/mobileAPI/FileNotificationById/{id}")
 Call> getFileNotificationById(@Path("id")Long id, @Query("access_token") String access_token);

El siguiente código obtiene lo de servicio. Este es mi activity. 
private void dowloand() {

```
    ImageView info = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dowloand);
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("ENTRE: " + notificationPk );
            NotificationService notificationUserBean = ServiceGenerator.createService(NotificationService.class);
            Call<ResponseBean<NotificationUserBean>> dbCall = notificationUserBean.getFileNotificationById(notificationPk,access_token);

            dbCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBean<NotificationUserBean>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBean<NotificationUserBean>> call, Response<ResponseBean<NotificationUserBean>> response) {


                    NotificationUserBean File = (NotificationUserBean) response.body().getData();
                    System.out.println("FIlE: " + File.getBtData());


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBean<NotificationUserBean>> call, Throwable t) {

                }

            });

        }
    });
}
```

}

En java solo envío un bean con un parámetro byte[]

Comment: Hola David. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta e incluir el código relevante de tu servicio web y cómo realizas la llamada al servicio REST? [mcve]

Comment: claro ahora lo hago. Disculpen soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Te sugiero darte una vueltar por el [tour] para hacerte una idea de cómo funciona Stackoverflow en español.